# WPF filtering ListBox after ComboBox selected changes c#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox, filtering

I have ComboBox binded to 1 datatable(1 column "Country") and listbox binded to another 1(2 columns "Name", "Country").
How to make listbox filter on selected item in combo box changes?

For example:

combobox values:
GER, POL, RUS

datatable binded to listbox:

```
Name | Country 
John | GER
Luke | POL
Sasha| RUS
CJ   | GER
Carl | POL
```

when I choose GER in combobox I want to refresh listbox to see only:
John
CJ

I used already filter to datatable

```
   dataSet.Tables["Name"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Country Like '%" + comboBoxFilter.Text + "%' ";
```

But I have result delayed by 1 click.

```
 change to | result

 GER       | no change
 POL       | now I see GER names
 RUS       | now I see POL names
 POL       | now I see RUS names
```

Why it is delayed?

Comment: can you post your binding or setting the itemssources?

Comment: listBoxNames.DataContext = dataSet.Tables["Names"];

Comment: Do you refresh table after filtering?

Comment: Yes I do. It does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combobox.text   is delayed for 1 event
```

to get actuall selected value in selection change event code I needed to

```
DataRowView drw = (DataRowView)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
string text = drw["Type"].ToString() ;
```